# How to specify optional argument within contract-out clause in Racket?

Tags: racket, option-type, contract

Given I have some function with signature like following

```
(define (my-method a [b 100])
    (/ a b)
 )
```

, how am I supposed to specify such signature in `contract-out`?

Using

```
(contract-out
          [my-method (-> number? number? number?)])
```

and then in another module

```
(my-method 200)
```

is not helping as it emits error saying "contract violation, received: 1 arguments, expected: 2 non-keyword arguments". And I guess I cannot just combine two contracts with and without optional using `or/c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `->*` and list mandatory arguments first (in a group), then optional arguments (in a second group), and then the result. There are more advanced options too; see the docs.

```
(contract-out
  [my-method
   (->* [number?]  ;; 1 mandatory argument
        [number?]  ;; 1 optional argument
        number?)])
```

This is covered in the [Contracts](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts.html) chapter of Racket Guide, on the section named [Optional Arguments](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts-general-functions.html#(part._contracts-optional)).